# Query SQL distinct by 4 fields (of 5), returning all fields from table

Tags: mysql, filtering, distinct

I have a table with five fields, and I need to filter it to be unique first four fields, but in result table I need all five. My function is searching all rows in table that equals data written in the search field, and looks like that:

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM `$userstable` WHERE `name` LIKE  '%inputName%' LIMIT 50;";
```

My table looks like this:

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
provider art   name   serie file
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
AAA      327   music  12FH  deal.wav
AAA      134   cowboy 943   cow.exe
AAA      327   music  12FH  blackjack.omg
BBB      327   music  12FH  deal.wav
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
```

In Result I want to see is something like this:

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
provider art   name   serie file
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
AAA      327   music  12FH  deal.wav
AAA      134   cowboy 943   cow.exe
BBB      327   music  12FH  deal.wav
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
```

UPD: It doesn't matter witch AAA string will be resulted `AAA      327   music  12FH  deal.wav` or     `AAA      327   music  12FH  blackjack.omg`

Comment: For the first record in your result,
AAA      327   music  12FH  deal.wav
what is the basis for selecting 'deal.wav' and not blackjack.omg?

Comment: I think your understanding of distinct in sql is causing some confusion.   To get distinct you must specify it in the select statement i.e select distinct(provider) .......   Even then you will get multiple rows where the records are not distinct as with the various files.   Try selecting each column name and do a group by the columns you want to be distinct i.e select provider, art, serie, file from table where name = @inputname group by (the columns you want)     that should give you a start.

Comment: Brian thanks, i rad about distinct and groupby again, and now I'm clear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) clause:

```
SELECT 
  provider, art,   name,   serie, file
FROM 
  `$userstable` 
WHERE 
  `name` LIKE  '%inputName%' 
GROUP BY 
  provider, art,   name,   serie
LIMIT 50
```

[MySql works with hidden fields](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html), that means that your `file` column may be some of the group file values. If you are looking for a specific value you need an [aggregate function ( max, min, group_concat, ... )](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) or a subquery.

Answer (score 2):

You should use group by instead of distinct:

```
select provider, art, name, serie, min(file)
from yourTable
group by provider, art, name, serie
```

I don't know wich database you're using. I've written the SQL in SQL server because thats what know, but i guess it won't be a problem to find the equivalent in your DB.